# C++ Same Letter Consecutively Program

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm trying to write a program using strings to determine if a word out of a file has two of the same letter consecutively in it. I wrote a function to do so:

```
bool likeornot(apstring word)
{
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if (toupper(word[i]) != toupper(word[i + 1]))
        return false;
}
return true;

}
```

Code in main:

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    fin >> word;
    if (likeornot(word))
        cout << "I like " << word << "." << endl;
    else
        cout << "I don't like " << word << "." << endl;
}
fin.close();
```

This is always returning false and telling me that it doesn't like any of the words, if anybody would help me figure out why that'd be fantastic.

Comment: You should test if the read succeeded or not before using the value after `fin >> word;`.

Comment: Yep, I have that, the program terminates if the file doesn't open.

Comment: Reading the file can fail even after opening the file (for example, when eof is reached). You should test the result after every time you read from the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More like

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
{
     if (toupper(word[i]) == toupper(word[i + 1]))
          return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: You can micro optimize this even further by keeping the last read value in a register. :p

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if (toupper(word[i]) != toupper(word[i + 1]))
        return false;
}
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
{
    if (toupper(word[i]) != toupper(word[i + 1]))
        return false;
}
```

You're going outside the string on the last comparison in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop needs to end at word.length()-1, not word.length() with this version you're always comparing the last character of the word with the character at the very end of the string, presumably a null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading past the end of the string, but you're unlikely to get that far because of this bug:

```
if (toupper(word[i]) != toupper(word[i + 1]))
  return false;
```

If the *first two letters* do not agree, the function returns `false`.